# How to build PyTorch dataset with mutliple arrays for different channel

Tags: pytorch, dataset, tensor, dataloader

I hope to know how to build up the dataset with multiple NumPy arrays as a data channel.
I have multiple arrays for 4-channel data as input and 1-channel data as an output.
For instance,
[Example of Data Structure - Tensor Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4rJo.png)

I think this form of data can be built with the below function,

```
from torch.utils.data.dataset import Dataset
```

But I am still having some issues to assign the tensor properly, specify the input, and output.
I hope to get some ideas or guides for this problem.

Thank you so much!